# Can I include td { } in an inline style attribute of my table?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a content management system that doesn't allow me to alter the head of the pages I'm working with. The page I'm creating will be edited by others using a WYSIWYG editor and will include a table where users can upload new documents. I want to style this with CSS so that I can give one command to put a line between each row (and this won't need to be done every time by each user - since they likely won't know how), but every time I do this it doesn't show anything. My code attempt is below, is this possible?

```
<table width=600px cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=2 style="td {border-bottom: solid 1px black;" }">
```

Answer (score 3):

Not that I'm aware of. But you can do this

```
<style type="text/css">
  .specialtable td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
<table width=600px cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=2 class="specialtable">
  ...
</table>
```

This will ensure that only this specific table's `<td/>` elements will be styled according to your needs. Note: according to the [w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3), `<style/>` is only allowed within the `<head/>` element of your document. But in many browsers, it still works if you put it anywhere in the `<body/>`. Since you're looking for **a kind of hack**, this may be a viable solution for you

Comment: @MrLister: Well, I'm aware of the fact that the OP cannot alter the head of the pages, but if he's willing to break HTML, he can maybe add the `<style/>` element right in front of the table...?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Had no idea I could just set up a style inside the body - this will come in very helpful.

Comment: Well, that is a bit of a hack. It's not valid HTML, but if you can live with that...

Comment: @MrLister: Yeah, I know it's a hack. I prefer your solution. When were those attributes added to HTML?

Comment: @user1350909: Yes, but don't abuse this hack ;-)

Comment: Let's see, they were not in HTML 3.2, so it must have been with HTML 4.0, in 1999.

Comment: @MrLister: Brand new to me :)

Comment: OK, related question: is there a way to retain my cellspacing but have the border-bottom be a continuous line? I'm thinking this would be something like a negative border-spacing value, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `frame` and `rules`, two lesser-known attributes of the [`table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE) element.

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" frame="below" rules="rows">
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
    <tr><td>five</td><td>six</td></tr>
</table>
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PmgJw/).

Or if you only want lines in between the rows and not below the bottom one, leave out `frame="below"`.

This won't work in all browsers though.